# How to install Java 9 and 10 on Mac with Homebrew?

Tags: java, macos, homebrew

I tried to install Java 9 and 10 on macOS with Homebrew:

```
brew cask install java9
```

I got the following error:

> Error: Cask 'java9' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

and:

```
brew cask install caskroom/versions/java9
```

gave me:

> Error: Cask 'java9' is unavailable:
>
> '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-versions/Casks/java9.rb'
>   does not exist.

Why doesn't this work and how can I install Java on macOS?

Comment: this may helps you....https://tecadmin.net/install-java-macos/

Comment: yeah I tried that, I can install Java 11 but not Java 9 or 10 :/

Comment: https://sdkman.io/ is an alternative to handling things like java which does have older SDKs on it. Can also switch between 8/9/10/11 etc. and install your own versions of software into it to handle the swtiching also.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oracle does not support Java 9 and Java 10 releases. users are advised to use Java 11 instead. Brew removed casks for both releases as well.

Here are the official links from oracle which mention that they removed support for Java 9 and Java 10.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html

When you will do `brew cask install java` it will install the latest version while you can still install java 8 by using `brew cask install java8`

Below github link from homebrew clearly mentioned that when oracle stops supporting java10 then they will remove java10 cask.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/pull/6305

**Summary**

`Java 9` and `Java 10` were non LTS(Long time support) releases from oracle and according to new release pattern from oracle, they will stop supporting non LTS release as soon as new version released thus Java 9 lost its support when 10 was released and Java 10 lost its support when 11 was released but Java 8 and Java 11 are LTS release so oracle will support it for long time.

Oracle stops supporting means download for those versions are not publicly available.

Comment: hmmm I wonder how you do library development and easily test with Java9 or Java10 or what not?

Comment: Java 9 and Java 10 were non LTS(Long time support) releases from oracle and according to new release cycles from oracle, they will stop supporting non LTS release as soon as new version released thus Java 9 lost its support when 10 was released and Java 10 lost its support when 11 was released but Java 8 and Java 11 are LTS release so oracle will support it for long time.

Comment: @andrew-janke answer to this question worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55775518/1420881

Comment: After installing the latest java version (in my case 13.0.1) I got an authentication issue from macos. Solved it this way: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372744/cannot-install-jdk-13-01-on-catalina?newreg=465bb4b3b0044287857a2a30cf590a09

Answer (score 43):

Those Oracle JDKs are no longer supported, and Homebrew core does not publish formulae for unsupported software.

Do you specifically need Oracle's JDK, or can you use any JDK? The AdoptOpenJDK JDKs are still available, and they're built from the same codebase as Oracle's JDK; just packaged differently. They do the same things as Oracle's JDK, pretty much. And they're still supported.

And as of Java 11, you may well need to switch from Oracle to OpenJDK, because Oracle [has ended the free licensing of the JDK](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/do-not-fall-into-oracles-java-11-trap.html).

To install the JDKs from AdoptOpenJDK:

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk9
brew cask install adoptopenjdk10
brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
```

Comment: My Mac still keeps Oracle's Jdk 12, and refuses to recognize what Homebrew installed.

Comment: If you have multiple JDKs installed, then the Java shims from macOS will typicall choose the newest one you have installed, so JDK 12 will be the default over JDK 9, 10, or 11. If you want to use the older ones, either uninstall JDK 12, set the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable, or modify your Java invocations to use version options with `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

Comment: brew cask install adoptopenjdk  #. this works as well.

Comment: Nowadays, you can leave out the "cask" bit and just perform commands like `brew install adoptopenjdk9` to perform the install of JDK 9

Comment: Thanks Rick! I'll update my answer once I have a chance to test this out.

Answer (score 17):

As of 2021, you should run

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
```

to make it work